# How to know if the driver cause the wifi network to be slow

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I have a linux server running ubuntu 16.04, and I recently bought a usb wifi adapter so my server could use wifi. But the network is not stable, frequently drop out and ping is high.

I ping it through a machine on the same network and router is less than 10 feet distance. the result is as follows：

```
LM-CHD:~ xuanyue$ ping 192.168.100.164
PING 192.168.100.164 (192.168.100.164): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=194.532 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=273.482 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=269.793 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=173.481 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=557.815 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=92.184 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
64 bytes from 192.168.100.164: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=163.623 ms
^C
--- 192.168.100.164 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 36.4% packet loss
```

This wifi adapter use Realtek [8822B chip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07695YGLZ). According to the buyer's comments there is no official driver support for this chip yet so I doubt the driver cause the network to be slow. But how can I confirm driver to be the root cause not something else?

lsusb, the last one

```
jinxuanw@jinxuanw-server:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

traceroute from server to macbook in the same network:

```
jinxuanw@jinxuanw-server:~$ sudo traceroute -I 192.168.100.107
traceroute to 192.168.100.107 (192.168.100.107), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.100.107 (192.168.100.107)  7.596 ms  7.550 ms  7.537 ms
```

ping 8.8.8.8:

```
jinxuanw@jinxuanw-server:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=252 time=635 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=252 time=212 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=252 time=174 ms
```

my macbook in the same network:

```
LM-CHD:~ xuanyue$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=252 time=232.117 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=252 time=25.959 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=252 time=24.984 ms
```

uname output: `4.13.0-37-generic`

log for dmesg: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JVtkSWVFSy/

Comment: You can check this command `traceroute 192.168.100.164` - print the route packets trace to network host.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` What is the result of: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: The driver in question is `8822bu`. Did you compile it from source code or is it included by default in your kernel? Please run: `uname -r` and also: `dmesg | grep -e wl -e 8822` and paste them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I compiled it from source and the github addr is `https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu.git`. I found it on amazon's customer reviews, I don't think it is in the kernel.

Comment: How about the paste? Maybe @Jeremy31 can look in and help us.

Comment: Looks crazy. I hope @Jeremy31 can help us.